# Akka stream 2.6. How to create ActorMaterializer?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Since 2.6 i get deprecation warning on this line:

```
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
```

Warning:

> method apply in object ActorMaterializer is deprecated (since 2.6.0):
>   Use the system wide materializer with stream attributes or
>   configuration settings to change defaults

I don't understand that message, what am i supposed to do? What's 'system wide materializer', it it located in some akka package?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's not needed anymore. But you have to have an `implicit` of `ActorSystem` available in your context.

```
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
```

Then the materializer is implicitly derived from `ActorSystem` in `akka.stream.Materializer`

```
  /**
   * Implicitly provides the system wide materializer from a classic or typed `ActorSystem`
   */
  implicit def matFromSystem(implicit provider: ClassicActorSystemProvider): Materializer =
    SystemMaterializer(provider.classicSystem).materializer
```

Comment: Yeah, but you need to have akka-stream as dependency.

Comment: @learn2code why would you need a Materializer if you don't use akka streams?