# object stream is not a member of package akka

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I've below build.sbt file -

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.7"

val akkaVersion = "2.6.18"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "akka-sbt-multijvm-issue"
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaVersion,
 "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % akkaVersion)
```

I've below main code -

```
package com.example

object MaterializerApp  extends App {

  import akka.stream.Materializer
}
```

when I compile the code I get the below error -

> sbt clean compile
>
> [info] welcome to sbt 1.6.1 (Azul Systems, Inc. Java 11.0.12)
>
> [info] loading global plugins from /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.sbt/1.0/plugins
>
> [info] loading settings for project akka-sbt-multijvm-issue-build from plugins.sbt ...
> [info] loading project definition from /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/akka-sbt-multijvm-issue/project
> [info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
>
> [info] set current project to akka-sbt-multijvm-issue (in build file:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/akka-sbt-multijvm-issue/)
>
> [info] Executing in batch mode. For better performance use sbt's shell
> [success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 5, 2022, 9:13:16 PM
> [info] compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/akka-sbt-multijvm-issue/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
>
> [error] /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/akka-sbt-multijvm-issue/src/main/scala/com/example/MaterializerApp.scala:5:15: object stream is not a member of package akka
> [error]   import akka.stream.Materializer
>
> ```
>                    ^
> ```
>
> [error] one error found
>
> [error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
>
> [error] Total time: 4 s, completed Jan 5, 2022, 9:13:21 PM

Note: When I change the `akkaVersion` to 2.6.17, the compilation succeeds.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: In akka 2.6.x the materializer import is not needed anymore, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58768399/akka-stream-2-6-how-to-create-actormaterializer/58768480 - So this is enough: `implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()`
`import system.dispatcher`

Comment: This compiles just fine for me... (the only clear difference I see is that I'm using the Oracle jdk11, but the Azul one - but it seems hard to believe that could be the difference.